# Android App similar to Windows Taskbar or Chrome OS Shelf?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to develop an android app that implements the same feature of Chrome OS Shelf/Windows Taskbar to android phones/tables? that is **always visible bar docked to the bottom of screen regardless of what application is currently running?**

### Chrome OS Shelf

[image]
*https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3UUc1Z3dvZDdYV0E/layout_structure_system_chrome.png*

### Windows Taskbar

[image]
*https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC420541.png*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.dock&hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the mentioned app uses overlay which is not quite what im looking for, to be more clear, the taskbar should be docked to the bottom of the phone/tablet and should be always visible and it doesn't overlay other applications, much like the regular android status bar on top.